# Specifying psqlODBC parameters in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, postgresql, odbc, sql-insert

Just began using PostgresQL for a vb application (using visual studio 2005 pro) and connect via ODBC (there's a reason for using the ODBC connection and not the native PostgresQL connector) .

I'm used to using the `@something` and `cmd.Parameters.Add("@something", data)` format with MSSQL.  I have 9 values i want to get from a form and use them in an insert statement but can't seem to figure the syntax for PostgresQL out.

Ideas? I've searched for two days trying to find an answer to this btw.

Edit:  Sorry, I already deleted the code I was trying, but I kept getting "the column does not exist" error on column "name" which is my first paramater.

I know it's not a connection error or a naming convention issue or something like that because the following code does work.   Here's how I'm doing it now for testing:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO tableb (name, extension, length,creationtime,lastaccesstime,lastwritetime,directoryname) VALUES ('Name','Extension','Length','CreationTime','LastAccessTime','LastWriteTime','DirectoryName')"

objConn.ConnectionString = strConnString
        objConn.Open()
        With objCmd

            .Connection = objConn
            .CommandText = strSQL
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        End With
```

Oh, and the ODBC version I'm using is 8.03.02.00

More info:
The code causing the error:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABLEB (name) VALUES (@name)"

    objConn.ConnectionString = strConnString
    objConn.Open()
    'Try
    With objCmd
        .Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Int)
        .Parameters("@name").Value = "SomeText"

        .Connection = objConn
        .CommandText = strSQL
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With
```

Code with parameters:

The exact error: ODBC Exception:

```
"ERROR [42703] ERROR: column "name" does not exist;
Error while executing the query"
```

The error occurs on the .ExecuteNonQuery

Thanks again!

Comment: Please *show your code* and *the exact text of any error that you get*, along with your PostgreSQL version ("select version()") and psqlODBC version. Do this by editing your question then adding a comment here when done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is with below code

```
.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.Int)
.Parameters("@name").Value = "SomeText"
```

you set name as `SqlDbType.Int` but you set text value to it

give correct column type when declare the parameters and assign correct value which match with given data type.

And also give parameters as `?` in sql statement and then add the command parameters in the same sequence given in the sql.  **ODBC do not support named parameters.**

sample code :

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABLEB (name) VALUES (?)"
objConn.ConnectionString = strConnString
objConn.Open()
With objCmd
    .Parameters.AddWithValue("name", "SomeText")
    .Connection = objConn
    .CommandText = strSQL
    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
    .ExecuteNonQuery()
End With
```

Comment: Perfect!, I knew I was missing something that had a ? or something!  So, since it's ordered, to add additional parameters I just have to use a sql staement like strSQL = "INSERT INTO tableb (name, extension) VALUES (?, ?)" and put my next parameter in the line below the first one.

Answer (score 0):

As written that query is fine. Given the stated error, likely issues are:

- Capitalization problems with quoting. If your column is defined as `"Name"` you need to refer to it as `"Name"` everywhere, not `Name` or `name`. See [lexical structure](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html).
- Accessing the wrong database or an older version of the same database you set up and forgot, one that contains a `tableb` without a `name` column
- In "anonymizing" the query you've hidden the real problem, or the error you quote doesn't match the code you're running. For example, quoting issues.

Are you sure the code you show is what you're getting the error from? You talk about `@parameter` etc in the text, but there's nothing like that in the code...

You should certainly be using *parameterized queries* instead of this approach to prevent [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) attacks, since I'm sure your *real* code doesn't hard code the values. Parameter use should be no different between psqlODBC and MS SQL Server's ODBC driver, that's half the point of query parameters. I don't speak Visual Basic (or ODBC if I can avoid it) and [the SQL injection rosetta stone](http://bobby-tables.com/) doesn't have details for VB.NET. Try doing what you do with MS SQL Server and if you have issues, follow up with a new question that includes the exact code and errors.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The column names in the db are all lower case.  Only one database is set up in PostgresQL.  The query I'm using right now works fine, and the data gets added to the tables correctly, it's when I try to use parameters using the @something and cmd.Parameters.Add("@something", data) method (as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx) that I run into the error.  So, the parameter place holder has to be different for PostgresQL or something...

Comment: @JimB OK, so the code you show *doesn't* match the error. Please edit the question so you show the *exact* code that you get the error from and the *full, exact text* of the error. Table definition (like `\d tablename` in `psql`) wouldn't hurt either. Remember to comment after an edit, otherwise notifications aren't sent.

Comment: Ok, had a second to rewrite the code in an abbreviated form and still get the same error.  Added the code and error to my question.  Thanks!

Comment: You said "Parameter use should be no different between psqlODBC and MS SQL Server's ODBC driver". However, I've used MySQL and MSSQL both, and they're parameter placeholders are different, mysql uses ? or $ (can't remember which) where mssql uses @.  So, I'm thinking PostgresQL is the same... I could be wrong though...

Comment: @JimB OK, that's different to JDBC and most of the other tools I've used, where they tend to keep parameter syntax uniform. Shocking if ODBC doesn't use a consistent placement syntax too.